# How to manage Domain DNS with Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to setup a Kubernetes Cluster with two master nodes and 5 simple nodes.
Every nodes is dedicated server on Linux.

I will setup two load balancer HAProxy server in front of them (On on Asia and One in EU managed by DNS Anycast).

My question is where the HAProxy will send request ? Only to the master or on every nodes ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You need to read up on Kubernetes architecture a little bit, specifically ingress and ingress controllers. [Here's some good information](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) to start you on your journey.